# translate url with google translate from python script

Tags: python, google-translate

I'm trying to use google translate from a python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from urllib2 import urlopen
from urllib import urlencode

base_url = "http://www.google.com/translate?"
params = (('langpair','en|es'), ('u','http://asdf.com'),)
url = base_url+urlencode(params)
print "Encoded URL: %s" % url 
print urlopen(url).read()
```

I'm getting the error 403 when I use it.

```
# ./1.py 
Encoded URL: http://www.google.com/translate?langpair=en%7Ces&u=http%3A%2F%2Fasdf.com
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

However the same URL works fine when accessed from browser. Could anyone spot the error? Or is it that google does not allow this type of usage?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If Google doesn't let you do this, you could programatically translate the normal website's source via the Google's APIs.

I wrote a function for this a little while back:

```
def translate(text, src = '', to = 'en'):
  parameters = ({'langpair': '{0}|{1}'.format(src, to), 'v': '1.0' })
  translated = ''

  for text in (text[index:index + 4500] for index in range(0, len(text), 4500)):
    parameters['q'] = text
    response = json.loads(urllib.request.urlopen('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/language/translate', data = urllib.parse.urlencode(parameters).encode('utf-8')).read().decode('utf-8'))

    try:
      translated += response['responseData']['translatedText']
    except:
      pass

  return translated
```

Answer (score 4):

You should be using the google [API](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlanguage/documentation/#Examples).  I found and tested this code, it works:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from urllib2 import urlopen
from urllib import urlencode
import sys
```

lang1=sys.argv[1]
lang2=sys.argv[2]
langpair='%s|%s'%(lang1,lang2)
text=' '.join(sys.argv[3:])
base_url='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/language/translate?'
params=urlencode( (('v',1.0),
                   ('q',text),
                   ('langpair',langpair),) )
url=base_url+params
content=urlopen(url).read()
start_idx=content.find('"translatedText":"')+18
translation=content[start_idx:]
end_idx=translation.find('"}, "')
translation=translation[:end_idx]
print translation

[source](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1087457)

Comment: However this is to translate text, not web page (leaving html tags inact). Is it possible to translate web page instead of text?

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the offical Google Translate APIs:

http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/apis/language/translate/overview.html

Apart from that:

http://www.catonmat.net/blog/python-library-for-google-search/

Comment: How do I translate an entire web page (not text) using google api?

Answer (score 0):

your problem is because you have no headers

(which tells google what is your browser and compatibility)

I had this error before when I made my google translate api

you can find it here: https://github.com/mouuff/Google-Translate-API

Answer (score 0):

you can use a much better python code for translating with google:

SOURCE: https://neculaifantanaru.com/en/python-code-text-google-translate-website-translation-beautifulsoup-new.html

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4.formatter import HTMLFormatter
import requests
import sys
import os

class UnsortedAttributes(HTMLFormatter):
    def attributes(self, tag):
        for k, v in tag.attrs.items():
            yield k, v

files_from_folder = r"c:\Folder2"
use_translate_folder = True
destination_language = 'vi'  #aici schimbi limba in care vrei sa traduci
extension_file = ".html"
directory = os.fsencode(files_from_folder)

def translate(text, target_language):
    url = "https://translate.google.com/translate_a/single"
    headers = {
        "Host": "translate.google.com",
        "Accept": "*/*",
        "Cookie": "",
        "User-Agent": "GoogleTranslate/5.9.59004 (iPhone; iOS 10.2; ja; iPhone9,1)",
        "Accept-Language": "fr",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
        "Connection": "keep-alive",
        }
    sentence = text
    params = {
        "client": "it",
        "dt": ["t", "rmt", "bd", "rms", "qca", "ss", "md", "ld", "ex"],
        "otf": "2",
        "dj": "1",
        "q": sentence,
        "hl": "ja",
        "ie": "UTF-8",
        "oe": "UTF-8",
        "sl": "en",
        "tl": target_language,
        }

    res = requests.get(
        url=url,
        headers=headers,
        params=params,
        )

    res = res.json()

    paragraph = ''
    for i in range(0, len(res["sentences"])):
        paragraph += res["sentences"][i]["trans"]

    return paragraph

def recursively_translate(node):
    for x in range(len(node.contents)):
        if isinstance(node.contents[x], str):
            if node.contents[x].strip() != '':
                try:
                    node.contents[x].replaceWith(translate(text=node.contents[x], target_language=destination_language))
                except:
                    pass
        elif node.contents[x] != None:
            recursively_translate(node.contents[x])

for file in os.listdir(directory):
    filename = os.fsdecode(file)
    print(filename)
    if filename == 'y_key_e479323ce281e459.html' or filename == 'directory.html': #ignore this 2 files
        continue
    if filename.endswith(extension_file):
        with open(os.path.join(files_from_folder, filename), encoding='utf-8') as html:
            soup = BeautifulSoup('<pre>' + html.read() + '</pre>', 'html.parser')
            for title in soup.findAll('title'):
                recursively_translate(title)

            for meta in soup.findAll('meta', {'name':'description'}):
                try:
                    meta['content'] = translate(text=meta['content'], target_language=destination_language)
                except:
                    pass

            for h1 in soup.findAll('h1', {'itemprop':'name'}, class_='den_articol'):
                begin_comment = str(soup).index('<!-- ARTICOL START -->')
                end_comment = str(soup).index('<!-- ARTICOL FINAL -->')
                if begin_comment < str(soup).index(str(h1)) < end_comment:
                    recursively_translate(h1)

            for p in soup.findAll('p', class_='text_obisnuit'):
                begin_comment = str(soup).index('<!-- ARTICOL START -->')
                end_comment = str(soup).index('<!-- ARTICOL FINAL -->')
                if begin_comment < str(soup).index(str(p)) < end_comment:
                    recursively_translate(p)

            for p in soup.findAll('p', class_='text_obisnuit2'):
                begin_comment = str(soup).index('<!-- ARTICOL START -->')
                end_comment = str(soup).index('<!-- ARTICOL FINAL -->')
                if begin_comment < str(soup).index(str(p)) < end_comment:
                    recursively_translate(p)

            for span in soup.findAll('span', class_='text_obisnuit2'):
                begin_comment = str(soup).index('<!-- ARTICOL START -->')
                end_comment = str(soup).index('<!-- ARTICOL FINAL -->')
                if begin_comment < str(soup).index(str(span)) < end_comment:
                    recursively_translate(span)

            for li in soup.findAll('li', class_='text_obisnuit'):
                begin_comment = str(soup).index('<!-- ARTICOL START -->')
                end_comment = str(soup).index('<!-- ARTICOL FINAL -->')
                if begin_comment < str(soup).index(str(li)) < end_comment:
                    recursively_translate(li)

            for a in soup.findAll('a', class_='linkMare'):
                begin_comment = str(soup).index('<!-- ARTICOL START -->')
                end_comment = str(soup).index('<!-- ARTICOL FINAL -->')
                if begin_comment < str(soup).index(str(a)) < end_comment:
                    recursively_translate(a)

            for h4 in soup.findAll('h4', class_='text_obisnuit2'):
                begin_comment = str(soup).index('<!-- ARTICOL START -->')
                end_comment = str(soup).index('<!-- ARTICOL FINAL -->')
                if begin_comment < str(soup).index(str(h4)) < end_comment:
                    recursively_translate(h4)

            for h5 in soup.findAll('h5', class_='text_obisnuit2'):
                begin_comment = str(soup).index('<!-- ARTICOL START -->')
                end_comment = str(soup).index('<!-- ARTICOL FINAL -->')
                if begin_comment < str(soup).index(str(h5)) < end_comment:
                    recursively_translate(h5)

            for h1 in soup.findAll('h1', {'itemprop':'name'}, class_='den_webinar'):
                begin_comment = str(soup).index('<!-- ARTICOL START -->')
                end_comment = str(soup).index('<!-- ARTICOL FINAL -->')
                if begin_comment < str(soup).index(str(h1)) < end_comment:
                    recursively_translate(h1)

        print(f'{filename} translated')
        soup = soup.encode(formatter=UnsortedAttributes()).decode('utf-8')
        new_filename = f'{filename.split(".")[0]}_{destination_language}.html'
        if use_translate_folder:
            try:
                with open(os.path.join(files_from_folder+r'\translated', new_filename), 'w', encoding='utf-8') as new_html:
                    new_html.write(soup[5:-6])
            except:
                os.mkdir(files_from_folder+r'\translated')
                with open(os.path.join(files_from_folder+r'\translated', new_filename), 'w', encoding='utf-8') as new_html:
                    new_html.write(soup[5:-6])
        else:
            with open(os.path.join(files_from_folder, new_filename), 'w', encoding='utf-8') as html:
                html.write(soup[5:-6])
```