# Using Python to translate Japanese to English

Tags: python, localization, language-translation

I am using Python to write some scripts that integrate two systems. The system scans mailboxes and searches for a specific subject line and then parses the information from the email. One of the elements I am looking for is an HTML link which I then use Curl to write the html code to a text file in text format.

My question is if the text in the email is in Japanese, are there any modules in Python that will automatically convert that text to English? Or do I have the convert to string to Unicode and then decode that?

Here is an example of what I am seeing. When I use curl to grab the text from the URL:

```
USB Host Stack 処理において解放されたメモリを不正に使用している
```

When I do a simple re.match to grab the string and write it to a file get this:

```
USB Host Stack æQtk0J0D0f0ã‰>eU0Œ0_0á0â0ê0’0Nckk0O(uW0f0D0‹0
```

I also get the following when I grab the email using the email module

```
>>> emailMessage.get_payload()
USB Host Stack =E5=87=A6=E7=90=86=E3=81=AB=E3=81=8A=E3=81=84=E3=81=A6=E8=A7=
=A3=E6=94=BE=E3=81=95=E3=82=8C=E3=81=9F=E3=83=A1=E3=83=A2=E3=83=AA=E3=82=92=
=E4=B8=8D=E6=AD=A3=E3=81=AB=E4=BD=BF=E7=94=A8=E3=81=97=E3=81=A6=E3=81=84=E3=
=82=8B
```

So, I guess my real question is what steps do I have to take to get this to convert to English correctly. I'd really like to take the first one which are Japanese characters and convert that to English.

Comment: are you using Python 2.x or Python 3.x? If you're using Python 2.x ... have you read anything about [`unicode`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#unicode)?

Comment: Convert to English how? Spell or translate?

Comment: The string is already Unicode. You can process the Japanese directly.  No "conversion" required.  If you want to translate Japanese to English, you need very, very sophisticated software.  Are you asking about NLTK?  Or are you asking about Google Translate?

Comment: Julio, I am using using python 2.x at the moment but if needed I can upgrade to 3.x. I have very little knowledge about unicode but I do understand it.

Comment: Sergio, I hope i understand your question. I want to translate the string to the English equivalent.

Comment: S.Lott, I am asking what is the best method I should use. So far I haven't had much luck at all. Doesn't seem like I can get the correct combination of Unicode/Decode to work or I am taking the wrong approach. NLTK or Google Translate. Which ever is best.

Answer (score 1):

Natural language translation is a very challenging problem, as others wrote. So look into sending strings to be translated to a service, e.g., google translate, which will translate them for you (poorly, but it's better than nothing) and send them back.

The following SO link shows one way: [translate url with google translate from python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871710/translate-url-with-google-translate-from-python-script)

Before you get that to work, you should sort out your encoding problems (unicode, uuencoding etc.) so that you're reading and writing text without corrupting it.

Comment: Thank you..the other part of this is the system is fully automated so it's going to be hard to automate the google part.

Comment: Note that the Google Translate api v1 has been recently deprecated and v2 is a paid service, so a lot of examples on the Web will no longer work.  Expect a lot of "Suspected Terms of Service Abuse" errors.

Comment: On another note...simple question since we are on the subject. Why doesn't the readline() give me back exactly what is present in the txt file I am reading? As you can see from my first exaple I do.

Comment: DSM you are correct. Those are the errors I received after I read the post. Does anyone know of another method? What if I just want to print exactly what is present? If the readlines() function reads Japanese print Japanese? As you can see from my first example I read in Japanese but when I print the line and write() it to a file they do not match. I am guessing this is UTF-8 or something else.

Comment: There are many possible character encodings. HTML files contain a header that tells your browser what encoding is in use. When you extract text with readline(), python does not look at the header and applies a default encoding. Check the header for the encoding you need, then read up on module codecs for the right encoding to pass to codecs.open()